# When starting Jmeter through batch file, I m getting : Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

## SLF4J: The class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/lib/tika-app-2.1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

How to resolve it,
and does it impact anything?

Answer (score 0):

This warning can be safely ignored.

If you're interested in the reason: this guy: `tika-app-2.1.0.jar` is not a part of JMeter 5.4.1 and both JMeter and Tika are using [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) framework with their own configurations. The framework detects both bindings and warns you about their presence in the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath)

If you don't use `tika-app-2.1.0.jar` anywhere in your Test Plans - remove the .jar from JMeter's "lib" folder and the warning will go away, moreover this .jar is kind of big and removing it will make JMeter to start faster.

Also according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider downloading [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) (or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.

Comment: tika-app-2.1.0, tika-core-1.24.1, tika-parsers-1.24.1 
Are you talking about these 3 files